# How to use AWS SageMaker and S3 for Object Detection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking to run a pre-trained object detection model onto a folder of ~400k images which is about 1.5GB. When I've tried running locally, it was estimated to take ~8 days to complete (with keras yolov3). Thus, I am looking to use AWS SageMaker and S3.

When I have uploaded the zip folder of my images in the SageMaker jupyter notebook and tried to unzip by using bash command, an error pops ups saying that I have insufficient space. The volume assigned to my notebook is 5GB EBS, I do have other heavy datasets in my jupyter notebook space which could be causing this issue.

To tackle that, I am looking for a way where I can upload my data to S3 and run SageMaker to read the images hosted and run an object detection model over. However, it does not look like there's a method to unzip folders on S3 without using an additional service (read that AWS Lambda may help) as these services are paid by my school.

I could possibly re-run my code to extract my images from URL. In this case, how can I save these images to S3 directly in this case? Also, does anyone know if I am able to run yolov3 on SageMaker or if there is a better model I can look to use. Appreciate any advice that may help.

Comment: You are going in right direction. Always data should reside on S3 and not on SageMaker instance.  Actaully, even after building the model; we save model file on S3. Biggest advantage is that u never loose your data or model even if tomorrow you terminate sagemaker instance.

Comment: If you have only 1.5 GB data; why don't u upload it without zipping it. That will remove your blocker.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have faced issues of uploading all 400k images from my windows file explorer without zipping it as it tends to crash with this many images. Are you aware if it is possible to download the images with URL straight into my S3 bucket?

Comment: umm ya got it; size is not the issue but huge number of files you have is the issue. Well you can write a small python script for it and run it on ur jupyter notebook in sagemaker.

Comment: Okay cool I'll try with that first! I've read somewhere about using AWS CLI to help with the upload as well. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes u are right u can upload thousands of images using aws cli using $aws s3 cp  ; or $aws s3 sync